# Vue: Append component to element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a vue component that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-autohide="true" data-delay="5000">
    <!-- HTML Clipped -->
    <div class="toast-body">{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title', 'message']
}
</script>
```

I then have an eventListener that listens for messages sent via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). This does work, but I don't think mount is the correct way to do what I want.

```
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
  let toastComp = Vue.extend(Toast)
  let toast = new toastComp({
    propsData: {
      message: 'hello'
    }
  }).$mount('.toast-container')
})
```

What I am looking for, is for vue to append the component to the `.toast-container` element instead of replacing the element. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about creating and appending an element inside of `.toast-container` and then mounting your component on to that new element:

```
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
  const toastContainer = document.querySelector('.toast-container')
  const mountNode = document.createElement('div')
  mountNode.id = 'mount-node'
  toastContainer.appendChild(mountNode)

  let toastComp = Vue.extend(Toast)
  let toast = new toastComp({
    propsData: {
      message: 'hello'
    }
  }).$mount('#mount-node')
})
```

Comment: instead of passing `#mount-node` to `$mount()` I think it would be better to pass `mountNode` element

Comment: Glad this helped you out :)

Comment: Where was Toast declared/set so that you could access it in the event listener?